# How to Post Form from View strongly Typed to ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model as such:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyObject myObject{ get; set; }
    public List<MyList> myList{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a view with a form strongly typed to `MyViewModel`

This view allows you to enter values for the properties of MyObject, as well as create a list of MyList objects. The List part works fine although I thought that would be the more difficult of the two.

Assuming MyObject has a property `Description` I create a textbox to enter the value as such:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.myObject.Description);
```

The text box renders with an id of `MyObject_Description`...The problem is when I post this to my controller action, MyObject does not get bound at all(althought the list items do as they recieve the appropriate IDs of "MyViewModel_MyList[guid].myListValue")

What am I doing wrong here??

**EDIT: more info**

The first line of the view is:
    `@model MyApp.ViewModels.MyViewModel`

And the Action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel myViewModel)
    {

    }
```

I am passing a new MyViewModel into the partial view to begin...

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok When I render my partial view that contains the forms I call :

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Create", "MyController");}
```

this is called from within a View of type `@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.MyObject>`
(this view displays a list of currently existing MyOjects, and at the bottom the partial is rendered to allow the user to add another MyObject to the DB)

Comment: Can you show the very first line of your View?  And the first/definition line of your Action method?

Comment: What does your controller method look like? Also are you rendering all the elements in a single page?

Comment: Also just to make sure does MyObject have a default constructor?

Comment: Yes MyObject is actually an EF object

Comment: Placed Get Create method in question above...just passing a new instance of MyViewModel...

Comment: Should myViewModel also have a default constructor to instantiate the object within it??

Comment: DefaultModelBinder should create instances by itself. I'd probably check whether values are actually posted

Comment: From the class show above it already does. It doesn't seem like you have a constructor explicitly defined on the class so the compiler creates one for you. I don't see any reason for this not to work. You mentioned id value for the textbox, what is the value of the name attribute? Since that is what is used by the default model binder.

Comment: yes the values are being posted

Comment: Sorry I meant to post the name of the controls not the ID... I am getting `MyObject.Description` as the name...I think it should be showing up as `MyViewModel.MyObject.Description` for this to work...

Comment: MyObject.Description should work. Are you rendering MyObject properties in a different partial?

Comment: Yes I have views where I am displaying MyObject properties and they work fine

Comment: Posted an answer that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not already doing so, try creating a editor template (e.g., Views->Shared->EditorTemplates) called MyObject.cshtml. Move your partial view content to this view and then call

```
@Html.Editor("myObject").
```

from your parent partial view.

Comment: Since this is actually a pretty complex view, Is there a reason you believe this would solve the problem?, you know before I spend a bunch of time on this lol

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and tried this real quick...If I remove everything to do with posting the MyList objects the `MyObject` works fine...as soon as I add the list back into the mix, The list works but the `MyObject` values stop getting passed....this is a really frustrating problem !

Comment: Still not solved but im gonna give you an upvote for your effort in helping me with this

Comment: I need a little more information to answer that's why  I said it might work. How are you invoking your existing partial for MyObject?

Comment: Ok added some more info under EDIT 2 above

Comment: I think I got this to work...I created another sample project and isolated this particular view scenario. I think the problem was related to the naming of the list object..as I dynamically added list items and named them `MyViewModel.MyList.MyValue`..I think this caused the model binder to ignor the `MyObject` properties that were not as strictly named. I will report back with my final results. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change your ViewModel to have the Description directly

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<MyList> myList{ get; set; }
}
```

then bind accordingly

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description);
```

Comment: Well I need to bind to other properties withing `MyObject`  Description was just my example

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the top line of your view to look something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyViewModel>" %>
```

This tells the view that the model it is supplied is of type `MyViewModel` (a la `<T>` style).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, this view is a partial view

Comment: Oh, well make sure you're passing the model object to the partial view properly.  How does that line of code look?

Comment: This is only true if he's using Aspx/Ascx pages, which he evidently isn't. He's using Razor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the out of the box model binding knows how to bind to complex objects. You're probably going to have to write up some sort of custom model binder.

I'm afraid it's not something I've done since MVC1 so I'm a bit hesitant to give you any sample code because the mechanism may well have changed completely since then. A quick google did turn up this article http://www.learnxpress.com/asp-net-mvc-hosting-6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding-2.html and this article http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt9-model-binders.html.

Edit: I've just seen this answer which might help [Retrieving data from view, should I use model binder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513091/retrieving-data-from-view-should-i-use-model-binder)